# Getting a Thread to wait indefinitely

Tags: java, multithreading, wait

I have a Java `Thread` which handles outgoing communication with a `Socket`. I only want the thread to run while there is pending output ready to be sent. Say I have a `Stack<String>` that holds the data waiting to be sent, I would like the comms thread to wake up when something is added to the stack and go to sleep when the stack is empty. Whats the best approach for this?

Options i see are;

1. Using `wait()/notify()` - now seems to be the old way of acheiving this behaviour
2. Having the thread check every x milliseconds if there is anything to be sent
3. Constructing a new `Thread` each time (expensive)
4. Having the thread run constantly (expensive)
5. Implementing some thread pool or executor solution

Any advice would be great :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`BlockingQueue`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) is exactly what you are looking for. Your communication thread blocks on `take()` and is woken up immediately when some other thread does `add`/`put`.

This approach has several advantages: you can have multiple threads (*consumers*) sharing the same queue to increase throughput and several threads (*producers*) generating messages (*message passing*).

Comment: Is it true that internally BlockingQueue uses wait and notify ?

Comment: @Pacerier: it's true that: `BlockingQueue` is an interface, so it can't use any synchronization as it has no code. It's also true that source e.g. of `ArrayBlockingQueue` implementation is freely available. If you look at it, you'll find `ReentrantLock` and `Condition` objects, not `wait` and `notify()`, at least in Sun's 1.6 implementation.

Comment: @TomaszNurkiewicz Ic, so ReentrantLock internally uses the sleep/interrupt pattern instead of wait/notify.

Comment: @Pacerier: I am not an expert in `java.util.concurrent` implementations, but looks like CAS (*compare-and-set*) operations are used as much as possible, see `java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer`

Answer (score 4):

You could use the java.util.concurrent library, if the data structures there meet your needs. Something like [BlockingQueue](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) might work for you.

Comment: + 1, thanks for the response, i marked the other as correct as it has slightly more info :)